# Matrix reporting Mismatched free() / delete / delete []

Tags: c++

Im new to programming and my program out seems to work just fine in visual studio but when I run it on matrix, I get this bug... The output in visual studio comes perfectly so I dont know why this is happening in gcc.

This is the bug:

```
Adding a new city to the country and migrating new people there
==245301== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==245301==    at 0x4C2B51D: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:586)
==245301==    by 0x40132E: sdds::Country::addCity(sdds::City const&) (in /home/s
==245301==    by 0x401984: main (in /home/smustafa14/ws)
==245301==  Address 0x5afdcd0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 108 alloc'd
==245301==    at 0x4C2AC38: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:4
==245301==    by 0x4010B2: sdds::Country::Country(char const*, int, sdds::City c
==245301==    by 0x40177E: main (in /home/smustafa14/ws)
==245301==
```

and I dont know why this is happenening since this doesnt show in visual studio.
I think my bug is producing in this code...

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iomanip>
    
using namespace std;


    // default constructor to set Country to an empty state
    Country::Country()
    {
        setEmpty();
    }

    // parameterized constructor to set the Country fields to specified values if valid
    Country::Country(const char* name, int noOfCity, const City* cities)
    {
        setEmpty(); // set Country to empty state
        // validate name, noOfCity
        if (name != nullptr && strlen(name) > 0 && noOfCity > 0 && noOfCity <= MAX_CITY) {
            // copy name, cities
            m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
            strcpy(m_name, name);
            m_noOfCity = noOfCity;
            m_city = new City[noOfCity];
            for (int i = 0; i < noOfCity; i++)
                m_city[i] = cities[i];
        }
    }

    // function to set the name of the Country
    void Country::setName(const char* name)
    {
        delete m_name; // delete existing name

        // validate input name
        if (name != nullptr && strlen(name) > 0)
        {
            // copy name
            m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
            strcpy(m_name, name);
        }
        else // invalid name
        {
            // delete m_city and set it to empty state
            delete[] m_city;
            setEmpty();
        }
    }

    // If the incoming City reference is not empty, this method will add the city to the m_city array of cities,
    // otherwise, the function is exited and no action will be taken.
    Country& Country::addCity(const City& c)
    {

        // validate input city is not empty
        if (!c.isEmpty()) {

            // expand the array
            City* temp = new City[m_noOfCity + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < m_noOfCity; i++)
                temp[i] = m_city[i];

            delete m_city;
            // add the city
            temp[m_noOfCity] = c;
            m_city = temp;
            m_noOfCity++;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // This function will receive the number of people who want to migrate to the list of cities m_city.
    Country& Country::migrate(int people)
    {

        // loop over the cities of the Country
        for (int i = 0; i < m_noOfCity; i++)
        {
            // population of the city is less than max population, add people to this city
            if (m_city[i].getPeople() < POPULATION) {
                m_city[i].addPopulation(people);
            }
        }

        return *this;
    }



    // Deallocate the memory allocated by m_name and m_city.
    Country::~Country()
    {
        delete[] m_name;
        delete[] m_city;
    }

    // function to display the Country details
    void Country::display()const
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Country Name: " << m_name << endl;
            cout << "No of city: " << m_noOfCity << endl;
            cout << left << setw(35) << "City name" << "Population" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < m_noOfCity; i++)
                m_city[i].display();
            }
            else
                cout << "Invalid country object" << endl;
        }
    
//This is the code that tests all the stuff above
int main(){
    cout << "Adding a new city to the country and migrating new people there" << endl;
    cu[3].addCity(c3);
    cu[3].migrate(8000);
    cu[3].display();
    return 0;
}
```

on visual studio, this is how the output is

```
Adding a new city to the country and migrating new people there
Country Name: Flower
No of city: 4
City name                          Population
|Lily                          |     20000|
|Tulip                         |     20000|
|Daisy                         |     18500|
|Rose                          |      8000|
```

Comment: `delete m_city` or `delete[] m_city`, only one is correct.

Comment: Also `delete m_name;` sb `delete[] m_name;`